# How to use protractor test to determine whether or not to publish my application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I need to automate the publishing process of my AngularJS application.

But I want to publish the application only when the protractor tests passes.

Is there any way to get a boolean output from the test? 
Or maybe using a task runner like `gulp` can do this trick for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we were doing was letting the task runner fail with a non-zero exit code which would mean our tests failed or there was an error during the test run.

In our case this was [`grunt-protractor-runner`](https://github.com/teerapap/grunt-protractor-runner) with [`keepAlive` set to `false`](https://github.com/teerapap/grunt-protractor-runner/issues/63). And, if `grunt` sees a non-zero error code returned by one of the tasks, it stops the execution and fails the whole macro-task itself, by default (without `--force`).

There are definitely other options:

- dump the test results into a junit XML (personally used `JUnitXmlReporter` from [`jasmine-reporters`](https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters)) and let your CI tool (say, `Jenkins`) parse the results and understand whether to continue or not
- set the [`resultJsonOutputFile`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/4924028c40b33821cc88d291328c6307859b5490/docs/referenceConf.js#L245) setting in your protractor config and parse it after a test run

To summarize - you should solve it on higher level, let your task runner, `grunt` or `gulp`, or a continuous integration tool, `Jenkins`, `Bamboo` or other, handle it.